# Checked all CheckBox of a Jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I am using Struts1.3, and in this Jsp page dynamically generate check boxes depends on the data available in Database. my code which is generate check boxes is as follow

```
<table width="850" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td width="100" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><label>
    <html:checkbox name="ExporterForm" value="<%=authlist.get(i).getAuthorityid()%>" property="exportauthority" styleId="checkbox99"  />
    </label></td>
    <td align="center" class="text_exp" ><%=authlist.get(i).getAuthorityname()%></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I have one more check Box(`selectAll`), and query is, I want to mark checked all while selection of selectAll CheckBox.

and my code is for checked all check box is given below but it's select only one and need to select all please show me the path to achieve it.

```
function selectAllAuthorites()
{
 var selectAll=document.getElementById("checkbox101")
 if(selectAll.checked==true)
 {
     document.getElementById("checkbox99").checked=true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **getElementsByTagName** method of Javascript.

This code might be of your help!

```
function checkAll() 
{
    //alert("Check all the checkboxes..."); 
    var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
        if (allRows[i].type == 'checkbox') 
        {
            allRows[i].checked = true;
        }
    }

}
```

You can call this function from your html checkbox.

**Edit**:

these links might help you.

[javascript-check-one-check-all-checkbox](http://www.toknowmore.net/e/1/javascript/javascript-check-one-check-all-checkbox.php)

[Javascript Function to Check or Uncheck all Checkboxes](http://www.somacon.com/p117.php)

[Another Link](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_onClick.html)

Comment: Thanks, Can u give me any example of submitting collection as a form in struts1.3. Or can you provide me the solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971017/in-struts1-3-how-handling-multiple-formbean-property-to-action

Answer (score 0):

Only one HTML element in a document may have a given ID. Your page is thus invalid. BTW, that's why the method is name `getElementById` (singular) and not `getElementsById` (plural).

Use `document.getElementsByName("ExporterForm")` and iterate through the returned list to check every checkbox of the list.